# How to create Static block that shows an random image

Tags: static-block

I want to create a static block which shows randomly one image from a specified image folder.
Does anyone know if this is possible and how to create it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Create a template file.
Let's call it `random.phtml`.
Put it in `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/random/random.phtml`.

The contents should look something like this:

```
<?php 
$images = array('img1.png', 'img2.png', ....);
shuffle($images);
$image = $images[0];
$url = Mage::getBaseUrl('media').'path/to/folder/'.$image;  
?>
<img src="<?php echo $url?>" alt="" />
```

make sure you put all your images in `media/path/to/folder`.  (feel free to change the name of the folder).

Now you can use this in 3 ways.

Either inside a static block:

```
{{block type="core/template" template="random/random.phtml"}}
```

either in any other template:

```
$block = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('random/random.phtml');
$html = $block->toHtml();
echo $html;
```

either in a layout file:

```
<reference name="left"><!-- not necessarily left. can be right, content, header... -->
    <block type="core/template" template="random/random.phtml" name="random-image" as="random-image" />
</reference>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create static block in your form steps:

1) go to -> Namespace_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Module_Edit_Tab_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form

Add code :
 $fieldset->addField('filenamelogo', 'text', array(
                    'name'      => 'filenamelogo',
            ));

```
  $form->getElement('filenamelogo')->setRenderer(Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('module/adminhtml_module_edit_renderer_logo'));
```

2) Create a file with name Logo.php on Block/Adminhtml/Module/Edit/Renderer/Logo

3) Add code in Logo.php
class Namespace_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Merchant_Edit_Renderer_Logo
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget
    implements Varien_Data_Form_Element_Renderer_Interface
{

```
public function render(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element) 
{ $html .= ' your html or php code '
return $html;
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create multiple static blocks, with a mutual identifier prefix:

Like:

> BannerIdentifier_1
>
> BannerIdentifier_2
>
> BannerIdentifier_3
>
> BannerIdentifier_4
>
> ...
>
> BannerIdentifier_N

Then pass your image to whatever block:

```
<a href="http://mystore.com/my_new_product/"><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/Banner/ban_1.PNG"}}" alt="Some alt text"  /></a>
```

Then call that static block on phtml file:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('BannerIdentifier_'.mt_rand(1, N))->toHtml() ?>
```

I am not sure if this is best, but it can be a way of doing this.